# Django: How can I filtering a foreign key of a class in models from users.forms

Tags: python, django

I create a Patient model in patient app

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Patient(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    birth_date = models.DateField()
```

I want filtering the doctor fields which is foreign key from Users for just groups='Docteur', so when I want to add a patient I can find the users with 'Docteur' groups only not the other account's group.

This is the forms.py in users app:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
import datetime

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES = []
    for years in range(1900,2021):
        BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES.append(str(years))
    sex_choice = [('1', 'Men'), ('2', 'Women')]
    groups_choice = [('1','Docteur'), ('2','Docteur remplaçant'), ('3','Secrétaire')]
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    sex = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=sex_choice)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES))
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.IntegerField()
    cin = forms.IntegerField()
    groups = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=groups_choice)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label='Password')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label='Repeat Password')

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('username','first_name','last_name','sex','date_of_birth','email','phone','cin','groups')
```

So what am I suppose to do to add this condition?

Comment: Show us your Doctor model

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a form for creating `Patient`s in which you can select a `User` for the `doctor` foreign key, but restrict the choices to users that have selected the `('1', 'Docteur')` choice as `groups` field.

In that case you can use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) and provide a filtered `queryset`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from .models import Patient

class AddPatientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    doctor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(groups='1'))
    
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', ...]
```

Comment: Exactly, but I think I have to change my Patient model to connect AddPatientForm(form.py) with Patient(models.py), or not?

Comment: @AkramBaklouti Yes for a ModelForm you have to specify the model in the Meta class. I updated the code to show this.